# Return to the same queue as network call was performed

Tags: ios, swift, networking, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I perform the next code

```
let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: requestData.body) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
}
```

All is clear, after doing network request in background I return completion to .main . But how to handle case, if I want to call completion not in .main but in thread in which session.uploadTask was initiated, because in my application it could be not only .main .

Answer (score 1):

There is not a GCD mechanism to retrieve the current dispatch queue so that you can later dispatch to it. (A long time ago, there used to be a way to fetch the current queue, but it was deprecated back in iOS 7, and even then it was “Recommended for debugging and logging purposes only.”)

If you want to call the completion handlers on specific dispatch queue, I would suggest supplying an explicit `DispatchQueue` parameter to the method. Below, I have it default to `.main`, but the caller can override that with whatever it wants:

```swift
func perform(_ request: URLRequest, with data: Data, on queue: DispatchQueue = .main, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
    let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            queue.async {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I know that this is not precisely what you are looking for, but it is an easy way to let the caller specify on which queue your closure will be called.

---

If you are using operation queues, you can get the [`current`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1413097-current) to determine the current operation queue. And should one do this, one would use [`addOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1412949-addoperation) on that operation queue in order to call the completion handler.

```swift
func perform(_ request: URLRequest, with data: Data, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
    guard let queue = OperationQueue.current else {
        fatalError("Must be called from operation queue")
    }

    let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            queue.addOperation {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

But this pattern only works if the caller was using operation queue, not when only using dispatch queues. For this reason, I would still be inclined to adopt the pattern of supplying the target operation queue as a parameter:

```swift
func perform(_ request: URLRequest, with data: Data, on queue: OperationQueue = .main, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
    let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            queue.addOperation {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to call completion on the current thread simply call `completion()`.

**current thread**

`completion(.failure(error))`

**main thread**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
```

**background thread**

```
Dispatch.global(qos: .background) {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution:

```
guard let currentDispatch = OperationQueue.current?.underlyingQueue else {
        return
    }

let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: requestData.body) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            currentDispatch.async {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
}
```

Have not tested it too much, but quick debugging shows what I wanted to achieve,

Comment: This obviously only works if you happen to be using operation queues for your background tasks. Furthermore, it only works if that operation queue has an `underlyingQueue` set. You can remove that second dependency by using `OperationQueue.current` directly, e.g., `guard let queue = OperationQueue.current else { ... }` and `queue.addOperation { ... }` rather than dispatching `async` to its underlying queue. That not only removes the dependency on `underlyingQueue`, but will honor the constraints for the operation queue, where as dispatching directly to the underlying dispatch queue won’t.